# How to convert excel sheet to List<int> bytes?

Tags: excel, flutter, dart

I am using [excel](https://pub.dev/packages/excel) dart package to edit my excel file. I need to convert the excel into a list of integer bytes List

```
var excel;
excel = Excel.decode(bytes)
```

Is that possible to convert the **excel** to again bytes (opposite of decoding) ?
There are other packages like [syncfusion_flutter_xlsio](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_xlsio) which have a property to save the workbook as List bytes like this:

```
List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
```

I don't want to use File system for read/write, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, it's in their tutorial and not very surprising:

```
final bytes = await excel.encode();
```

Comment: but it's not a List<int> I guess

Comment: Why do you need a list of ints? An excel package is not made of ints, it's made of bytes. How would you like your ints to look? Which bytes would you like to form into an int (high order/low order?) and does the receiver know that? What happens if the number of bytes is not enough to form a full int at the end? How would you like to treat that?

Comment: I used type cast and it worked, I need the bytes of list to change it into a Stream of bytes(Stream<List<int>>) for uploading it to google drive using drive api v3 , "final List<int> bytes = (excel.encode()) as List<int>;" If you could edit your answer then I could accept that as an answer. Thanks